# Understanding a composite figure proof (circle within triangle within circle)

Tags: geometry, area

I stumbled upon [this page](https://brilliant.org/wiki/basic-composite-figures/#length-and-area-composite-figures) on Brilliant the other day with this problem.

[image: https://ds055uzetaobb.cloudfront.net/brioche/uploads/cUrut3pKVx-geometryarea.JPG?width=2000]

My main issue isn't necessarily the problem itself. I have more of an issue with their supposed solution:

[image]

I just don't understand how this proves that the area of the circle is equal to the sum of the two blue areas. I've been staring at this image for hours now, and cannot make out what they are trying to convey.

I made some observations, but none that lead me to the solution:

- The outer triangles can be folded in to make a hexagon that covers
  the circle, and the inner circle would be the incircle of that hexagon.
- The problem is equivalent to showing that the smaller circle makes up
  0.25% of the larger circle.
- The larger circle outside of the smaller circle clearly makes up 3 times the
  area of the blue region.

I want to understand this visual solution. Sure, there's another way of solving this:

1. compute the side lengths of the triangle by using the equilateral triangle created by the radii of the larger circle (since the angle of this equilateral triangle is obvious)
2. Use that to figure out the radius of the inner circle (using the right kite it forms by using two of the points in touches the triangle)
3. compute the inner circle area and divide by the total area

However, if there's a solution that doesn't require long computations, I want to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the first drawing in the post is supposed to exhibit why the radius of the big circle is double the radius of the first circle, and the second drawing (which you don't include) is supposed to show why the blue area is a third of the complement of the orange circle.

The proof is just: The radius of the small circle is one little triangle height, while the radius of the large circle is two little triangle heights.

Answer (score 0):

The small circle have half big circle radius so $A=4r^2\pi$
And $a=r^2\pi$ the remaining is the $3r^2\pi$ divide by three and you are done

Comment: I showed that the small circle have fourth the big circle area

Comment: How did you show that the small circle has half the radius of the big circle?

Comment: Join the center C with the vertex A (any vertex) of the triangle that would bisect the angle so it is 30 degrees draw right triangle ACB where B is the mid of side with A  as a vertex. In a right triangle the side opposite of the angle with 30 degrees have half the length of the hypotenuse. But the side opposite of the 30 degree is the radius of the small circle and the hypotenuse is the radius of the big one

Comment: Well, that's true. That should've been in the answer itself.